# How can nested array works in implode function for insert sql?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, implode

This works fine for

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple">Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="orange">Orange
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">

$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$insert = $db->insert($tblName,$_POST);

public function insert($table,$data){
   if(!empty($data) && is_array($data)){
        $columnString = '';
        $valueString  = '';
        $columnString = implode(',', array_keys($data));
        $valueString = ":".implode(',:', array_keys($data));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columnString.") VALUES (".$valueString.")";

        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($data as $key=>$val){
             $query->bindValue(':'.$key, $val);
        }
        $insert = $query->execute();
        return $insert?$this->db->lastInsertId():false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

However,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple">Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange">Orange
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
```

It doesn't work. How could I modify the above function to work for fruit[] too?

In my database, I want to group "fruit" into one column (e.g. fruit => apple, orange, pear) and "lang" into another column.

Many thanks.